Clicking on Edit Icon in Cart Item Routes to the Wrong Item
I have a React application with a cart that contains multiple items. Each item has an Edit icon that, when clicked, should navigate to addons or customization based on whether the item has add ons or not. If item has addons, it should navigate to addons otherwise customization.
  const cartItem = useMemo(
    () => (cart.length === 0 ? null : cart[cart.length - 1]),
    [cart]
  );

  const addons = useMemo(() => cartItem?.item.addons || [], [cartItem?.item.addons]);

  const handleItemEdit = useCallback((id: string) => {
    if (addons.length > 0) {
      updateStepData(customizationStep.formKey, () => ({
        itemId: id
      }));
      navigate(`/checkout/addons`);  
    } else {
      navigate(`/checkout/customization`);
    }
  }, [addons, navigate]);

The problem I'm facing is as follows:
Case A: Let us suppose there are two items in the cart with addons:

The first item with extras is at the top with an Edit icon.

The second item with extras is at the bottom with an Edit icon.

When I click on the Edit icon of the first item, it navigates to the page of the second item.

When I click on the Edit icon of the second item, it correctly navigates to its own page.


Case B: Additionally, there can be a case where there are three items in the cart:

The first item with no addons.
The second item with addons.
The third item with addons.

When I click on the Edit icon of the first item, it navigates to the third item with addons, where it should display no addons and point to the customization route.

Do both items have addons?, if yes, then you are using if statement incorrectly

Yes, both items have addons for the case above.

Additionally, there can be a case where there are three items in the cart:

The first item with no addons.
The second item with addons.
The third item with addons.

When I click on the Edit icon of the first item, it navigates to the third item with addons, where it should display no addons and point to the customization route.

Well, i found something interesting, your first useMemo is returning cart[cart.length - 1] (last element of the cart array) in case cart is not empty, so when you have a cart that has elements (in your case 2 or 3), cartItem will surely be the last member of the array, that's probably why it's navigating to the last item, and since in both cases your last item has addons, the route will be "addons" instead of "customization". Maybe you should think of specifying cartItem with a dynamic index (for example for first item cart[0] instead of cart[cart.length - 1])

Based on the code it looks like all items would navigate to the same page since there are only two static target paths. Can you [edit] to clarify the problem in better detail and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

@HairyHandKerchief23 Here is the component https://jsfiddle.net/y163L45f/ Let me know if you need more information or code.

@flash, check this link, i've tried to help with something more "dynamic".

Perhaps it would be useful and helpful to explain exactly what "navigates to the page of the second item" and "navigates to its own page" means. I still see only the two target paths that presumably all items's edit button target via this handleItemEdit handler. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] so readers here can better understand what you code is trying to do.
